# 301 Redirect Help with Dynamic URL's and Multiple Id's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I just did a redesign for www.wildchildclothes.com which has a new URL structure. The old site ran on Zen Cart and had a bad URL structure. Here are some examples of what I want to redirect from:

OLD: www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21
NEW: www.wildchildclothes.com

and...

OLD: www.wildchildclothes.com/index.php?main_page=faq_info&fcPath=0&faqs_id=13
NEW: www.wildchildclothes.com/customer-service.html

Here is what's in my .htaccess to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*chapter=1(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*id=21(&|$)
RewriteRule ^page\.html http://www.wildchildclothes.com? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*main_page=faq_info(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*fcPath=0(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*faqs_id=13(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.wildchildclothes.com/customer-service.html? [L,R=301]
```

But this doesn't work at all - I only get sent to my 404 page instead of begin redirected. Can anyone shed some light? The full .htaccess is posted below.

Thanks much,
Jonah

Comment: What do you mean by 'don't work'? The rule doesn't match, or redirects somewhere else? Also have a look in the rewrite log (see the docs for RewriteLog ), that often helps to shed some light on these things...

Comment: They don't redirect to where I'm trying to redirect to (in the examples above http://www.wildchildclothes.com) and I'm not sure if my rules are not matching or I just don't have the right code at all. 

In my first example above, should my rules match for www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21 and redirect to www.wildchildclothes.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above solutions worked for me, but this does:

To redirect www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21 to www.wildchildclothes.com:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} chapter=1&id=21
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wildchildclothes.com/? [R=301,L]
```

To redirect www.wildchildclothes.com/index.php?main_page=document_product_info&products_id=280 to www.wildchildclothes.com:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} main_page=document_product_info&products_id=280
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wildchildclothes.com/? [R=301,L]
```

To redirect www.wildchildclothes.com/index.php?main_page=faq_info&fcPath=0&faqs_id=9 to www.wildchildclothes.com/customer-service.html:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} main_page=faq_info&fcPath=0&faqs_id=9
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wildchildclothes.com/customer-service.html? [R=301,L]
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this but this works for me and .htaccess just gives me a headache so I'm not digging any further.

I hope this helps someone else out there!

- Jonah

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and far better if you use PHP for the redirect. You could, for example, rewrite such requests to a PHP script that analyzes the URL arguments and redirects to the correct page. Maybe something like this:

```
// old-to-new.php
$rules = array(
    array(
        array('chapter' => '0', 'id' => '23'),  // old URL parameters
        '/customer-service.html'                // new URL
    ),
    // …
);
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if (array_intersect_assoc($rule[0], $_GET) == $rule[0]) {
        header('Location: http://example.com'.$rule[1], true, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
exit;
```

And the corresponding `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ old-to-new.php [L]
```

Comment: I created a redirect.php in the root with this in it:
$rules = array(
    array(
        array('chapter' => '1', 'id' => '21'),'/customer-service.html'));
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if (array_intersect_assoc($rule[0], $_GET) == $rule[0]) {
        header('Location: http://www.wildchildclothes.com'.$rule[1], true, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
exit;

And added this to the .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ redirect.php [L]

But that doesn't redirect http://www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21...

Comment: @Gumbo: do you mean when you go to www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21 it redirects or that the code works for you?

Comment: @Jonah: No, if I request that URL path from your website I don’t get redirected. But on my localhost it works like a charm. But if you take a look at http://www.wildchildclothes.com/redirect.php?chapter=1&id=21 you’ll see that your PHP script is corrupt. You’ve probably missed to put the PHP code into PHP tags `<?php … ?>`.

Comment: Wow, I have been working on this too long that I've become blinded from the obvious. You're right, I forgot the php tags. I added them and now wildchildclothes.com/redirect.php?chapter=1&id=21 works. But, how do I get the redirect to happen for someone trying to visit www.wildchildclothes.com/page.html?chapter=1&id=21 ?

I'm assuming thats where the RewriteRule comes into play but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jonah: Maybe you’re missing something mandatory again: Do you use `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: @Jonah: Do you use any other rules that might get in conflict with mine?

Comment: See below, I just posted the full .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You want to allow more than one character in the query parameters.  Change `[^&]&` to `[^&]*&`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*chapter=1(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*id=21(&|$)
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ http://www.wildchildclothes.com? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*main_page=faq_info(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*fcPath=0(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*faqs_id=12(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.wildchildclothes.com? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy but this still does not work. It just takes me to my 404 page. Any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add `RewriteEngine On`?  Can you do a simple redirect like `RewriteRule . http://google.com`?

Comment: RewriteEngine is On, could it have anything to do with DirectoryIndex index.html index.php?

Comment: No, `DirectoryIndex` shouldn't make a difference.  Again, does `RewriteRule . http://google.com` work?

Comment: Here is a demo that works for me: http://steindevelopment.com/wildchildclothes/demo.html

Comment: Yeah, looks good and thanks for going to all the trouble in helping me and setting up examples - I don't know what the problem could be for me... I inserted the exact same code as you're using (with a dif. rewrite base) but it does not work. I'm about ready to give up though. I have most of our links redirected and it doesn't feel worth it to spend hours on 20 or so links that won't redirect. I have other conditions and rules in my .htaccess so this may be conflicting as Gumbo suggested above...

Comment: I just posted the full .htaccess for reference.

Comment: @Jonah, please start with just my .htaccess and see if that works.  Then, piece by piece, add in the other parts you want and see where it breaks.

Comment: You can't try it in a subdirectory or on a testing site?

Comment: Alright, I setup a dev copy of the site @ wildchildclothes.com/dev and used only the above rules in the .htaccess (also added RewriteEngine on & RewriteBase /dev/) but it still doesn't redirect when I try visiting http://www.wildchildclothes.com/dev/page.html?chapter=1&id=21

Any other ideas?

Comment: Figure out exactly which part is breaking it.  Start with redirecting on all URLS.  Then add page.html.  Then add one RewriteCond.  If that breaks, try simplifying it.  Find the smallest possible change you have to make to go from a .htaccess that works to one that doesn't.